# ShareThis script GET fails for one known computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharethis, getscript

Issue is a failure to load ShareThis script.

This has been tested without issue on 8 different computers.  The one where the issue occurs is (of course) the client's laptop.  Running Windows 8 the issue occurs in both Chrome and FireFox.

Script is initialized in javascript file like so:

```
$.getScript("http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js", function() {
        var switchTo5x = false;
        stLight.options({publisher: "my-uid-here", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false, shorten:false });
    });
```

On client's machine we see

[image: error1]

and

[image: error2]

Interestingly there is no request method or status code in client's headers for only this one file.  Others have method and and 200 or 304 code.

[image]

Sorry - client's screenshots are huge.

So my question is what conditions on a single computer could be blocking ShareThis?  I have not see AdBlock or similar have issues with it before...

Comment: Can you show the response headers / body? Might be some clever anti-virus? Firewall? - He might have a cached version of that bit of js that uses an invalid API key?

Comment: I will see about getting him to cap the headers.  Rather doubt it is an invalid key as site and key are new. Thanks for response!

Comment: Have added screenshot of headers for the file.  Interestingly there is no request method or status code in client's headers for only this one file.  Others have method and 200 or 304 code.

Comment: No anti-virus or firewall installed on clients computer? Did she try from a different network (3G or different wifi network)?

Comment: He's running Avast but I had him disable it.  No change.  No firewall he is aware of and definitely none with a special config.

Comment: I've asked him to try another network.